# Automatically restart SQL Server Replication after server restart

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, transactional-replication

After restarting the Windows Server on which SQL Server is running I get the following error in my Application Event Log:

```
Replication-Replication Distribution Subsystem: agent <name removed> failed. The subscription(s) have been marked inactive and must be reinitialized. NoSync subscriptions will need to be dropped and recreated.
```

Is there any way to automatically reinitialize the subscription or what is the best way to restart a server with replication running on it?

Johan

Answer (score 0):

I was too quick. Managed to find the answer by setting the job to auto start when SQL Server Agent starts....
https://microsoft.public.sqlserver.replication.narkive.com/D84GcvnT/replication-not-automatically-starting-after-server-reboot